# Undefined rails method on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just pushed some changes heroku and now my app is broke, even though it runs find in dev. Here is what 'heroku logs' is saying...

```
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_type' for #<User:0x007f1f2ca092e8>):
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712897+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__form_html_erb___784052068966039252_69885941331520'
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:   </div>
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   <div class="field">
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:     <%= f.select :user_type, options_for_select(['Bar', 'Brewery', 'Restaurant', 'Hotel'], @user.user_type) %><br/>
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:   </div>
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/_form.html.erb:26:in `block in _app_views_users__form_html_erb___784052068966039252_69885941331520'
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:   <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Sign Up" %></div>
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712744+00:00 app[web.1]:     29: <% end %>
2013-11-07T18:58:47.712897+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___2270355414211974343_69885950076300'
```

Looks like it does not like   <%= f.select :user_type, options_for_select(['Bar', 'Brewery', 'Restaurant', 'Hotel'], @user.user_type) %>
 Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run your database migrations on Heroku? Do you have more than one class called `User` in your application?

Comment: Yes...have ran migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being the version of Ruby that I was using. I did not specify the ruby version in my Gemfile. I am using 1.9.3 in dev, but Heroku defaults to 2.0. I added the line...

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

to the bottom of my Gemfile and I was good to hook.

Answer (score 0):

Run all migrations for you application and then restart your app with `heroku restart`.